# C - freeing memory of a binary tree using post-order traversal

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I want to **remove a binary tree using post-order traversal**. Meaning the left part of the tree should be removed first then the right one **then remove the whole tree and free memory** in a second function that follows after. I'm not allowed to changed the arguments of the function and can only play with the inside of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "telefonbuch.h"

static inline bstree * create_node(unsigned long phone, char * name)
{
  bstree * newNode = (bstree *) malloc(sizeof(bstree));

  newNode->key.phone = phone;
  strcpy(newNode->key.name, name);
  newNode->left = NULL;
  newNode->right = NULL;

  return newNode;
}

void bst_insert_node(bstree * bst, unsigned long phone, char * name)
{
    if (bst == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (bst->key.phone > phone)
    {
        if (bst->left == NULL)
        {
            bst->left = create_node(phone, name);
            return;
        }

        bst_insert_node(bst->left, phone, name);
    }
    else
    {
        if (bst->right == NULL)
        {
            bst->right = create_node(phone, name);
            return;
        }

        bst_insert_node(bst->right, phone, name);

    }
}

bst_node * find_node(bstree* bst, unsigned long phone) {
  if (bst == NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }

  if(bst->key.phone > phone)
  {
      return find_node(bst->left, phone);
  }
  else if (bst->key.phone < phone)
  {
      return find_node(bst->right, phone);
  }

  return &(bst->key);
}

void bst_in_order_walk_node(bst_node* node) {
}

void bst_in_order_walk(bstree* bst) {
   int temp = 0;
   int level;

   while(temp < level)
   {
       printf("-");
       ++temp;
   }

   printf(" (%ld-%s)\n", bst->key.phone, bst->key.name);

   if (bst->left != NULL)
   {
      print_tree(bst->left, level + 1);
   }

   if (bst->right != NULL)
   {
      print_tree(bst->right, level + 1);
   }
}

void bst_free_subtree(bst_node* node) {

    …what goes here?…

}

void bst_free_tree(bstree* bst) {
  if(bst==NULL)
      return;
  bst_free_tree(bst->left);
  printf("Deleting %d node.\n",bst->key);
  free(bst);
  bst_free_tree(bst->right);
}
```

Here are the structure definitions:

```
typedef struct _bst_node {
  char name[60];
  unsigned long phone;
} bst_node;

typedef struct _bstree {
  bst_node key;
  struct _bstree * left;
  struct _bstree * right;
  } bstree;
```

Could you help me finish/correct my code?

Comment: I don't understand what `bst_free_subtree` is supposed to do. Its argument is a node, so you can't release a whole subtree with it. BTW your function `bst_free_tree` is partially wrong, because `bst->right` is used after `bst` is freed. You have to move the statement `free(bst)` _after_ your calls.

Comment: hey Ahmed, I'm having trouble with this as well, are you sure that free_subtree's signature is valid? could you please post all signatures for all functions? and I'd be able to solve this for you :)

Comment: It seems to me that `bst_free_tree` does the entire job just fine on its own. What do you need `bst_free_subtree` for? (The story would be different if the definition of the `bstree` struct included `bst_node *key;` instead of `bst_node key;`.)

Comment: I posted the whole program :)

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
void bst_free_tree(bstree* bst) {
  if(bst==NULL)
      return;
  bst_free_tree(bst->left);
  printf("Deleting %d node.\n",bst->key);
  free(bst);
  bst_free_tree(bst->right);
}
```

This deletes the current node 'in-order', and accesses the freed memory after freeing it.  Not good!

You need a close relation:

```
void bst_free_tree(bstree* bst)
{
    if (bst == NULL)
        return;
    bst_free_tree(bst->left);
    bst_free_tree(bst->right);
    printf("Deleting %d node.\n", bst->key);
    free(bst);
}
```

This traverses and releases the left sub-tree, then the right sub-tree, and then finally releases the current node.

I don't see a need for the `bst_free_subtree()` function; the `bst_free_tree()` function frees sub-trees equally well.